# Write a MATLAB function that calculates the temperature of a conductor when given a current and all necessary parameters as inputs

Tags: matlab

```
h = 11;                 
D = 0.02614;                                     
Tinfinity =302 ;         
sigma = 5.67*(10^-8);  %Variables
epsilon = 0.3;          
alpha = 0.6;           
Gs = 1200;              
R = 0.00007;     


for I=1:1:720
pF1=@(T) h.*pi*D.*(T-Tinfinity)+sigma.*epsilon.*pi*D.*((T.^4)-     (Tinfinity.^4))-alpha.*D.*Gs-(I.^2)*R;
T(I) = fzero(pF1,0); %T is temperature and I is current

end
plot (I,T)      %I cannot get it to plot a graph
xlabel('Current ');             
ylabel('Temperature ');
```

%My issue is that I cannot get it to graph anything given all variables except for T, Temperature

Comment: Are yoy getting any error message? Have you check the content in both variables?

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes in you code related to I vector and looping. Please try following code:

```
h = 11;                 
D = 0.02614;                                     
Tinfinity =302 ;         
sigma = 5.67*(10^-8);  %Variables
epsilon = 0.3;          
alpha = 0.6;           
Gs = 1200;              
R = 0.00007;     

II  = [1: 1: 720]  ;
for I=1:length (II)
pF1=@(T) h.*pi*D.*(T-Tinfinity)+sigma.*epsilon.*pi*D.*((T.^4)-(Tinfinity.^4))-alpha.*D.*Gs-(I.^2)*R;
T(I) = fzero(pF1,0); %T is temperature and I is current

end
plot (II,T)      %I cannot get it to plot a graph
xlabel('Current ');             
ylabel('Temperature ');
```

In your code I was looping variable and it was holding the final value of loop which is 720. However, you were trying to plot the T Vs I then all values of T was plotting for a single value of I.

Comment: I suggest adding the explicit answer: `I` is the last value in the `for` loop, hence a scalar, and `T` is a vector, so you can't plot `T` vs `I`, you need a vector for the current as well.

Comment: It says line 16 has an error and that the vectors need to be the same length.

Comment: I sent you working code, Please copy the code from my answer and try once again

Comment: I copied it exactly and it gives these errors: https://gyazo.com/a5b2c49ff05cfac95ed83ee67309ac72
Would it be because of different versions of matlab?

Comment: which version of matlab you have?

Comment: matlab version R2015b

Comment: I have R2014a.  Please copy the error message as  comments

Comment: Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length.

Error in new (line 16)
plot (II,T)

Comment: Have you tried to compare the length of both vectors. Please trey: length (II) and length (T) commands

Comment: ahh they are different lengths

Comment: Copy the code in my answer and create and new script file and try it there

Comment: OHmygod it graphs something! i got this https://gyazo.com/ad764de435628c3f9b3cd93b5c7a6cba
Thank you so much!

Comment: I cannot describe how grateful I am for your help. I truly thank you for everything.

Comment: Can you tell me what was the problem. I am asking for curiosity.

Comment: what i did was use the clear command and then tried running it again. I guess it had old variables that messed up the values